# Log in as domain user with local administrator access

Tags: windows, security, active-directory

Sometimes (e.g. when inspecting malware infested machines) it is very useful to be able to log in as a domain user without knowing the user's password with the computer off-line. How to do it? In every case, a local computer administrator account is available.

One option I am aware of involves dumping the cached domain credentials and then cracking them, but that means that password is no longer secret and sometimes is simply not practicable. 
In linux/unix, I would just do sudo -u 'johndoe' and be done. What's the equivalent in Windows XP/Vista/7?

Edit: just to provide context. This is for inspecting malware infected machines. Some malware will only start if you log on as the originally infected user. I can't put it back on the network to reset the password as it would be too risky. So, the box is off-line and I have a local admin account which is created at install time for troubleshooting.

Comment: Log in as the Administrator and go ahead. It works.

Comment: @maliq - Eh? What works?

Answer (score 5):

There is no `su` in the windows world.

The only option short of getting the user to login is to change the user's password in active directory.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with managed (.Net) custom code.  Beginning with Windows 2003/XP, there is a feature called S4U, that enables impersonation without credentials or an existing token.

I'm not providing a code sample, but if you know someone that can code this is fairly straightforward.

So the upshot is it is possible to run something like impersonate.exe [domain\username] and open a new command prompt in that user's identity.  Is that what you had in mind?  If so, you may want to close this and open a new question on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase your question ... if I am not correct please advise.

> How can I log in to a machine with administrative privileges when it is off the network?

The most straight-forward option (in advance) is to setup Group Policies that force the local administrator password to a known password. Then, even if the PC is off the network, the local admin account will be available.

Answer (score -2):

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

I recommend this. Burn it to a disc/flash drive and go for it.

Comment: Only works for local accounts, in a domain environment there are precious few of them (thankfully).

Comment: That tool resets local accounts. Did you read the question?